# How to get GPU temperature programmatically in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, gpu, sensors

I am trying to get GPU temperature on mac's OSX platform programmatically

I tried to google for solutions but I can't find it , all I could find is CPU temperature and GPU usage in percentage.

Is there some API or library that allows to retrieve the sensors data ?

can someone please tell me where to start ?
or maybe provide some example?

Comment: [Fan Control](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/FanControl/index.html) Prefpane is open source (GPL). The sources are included in the download.

Comment: @Emmanuel it is for CPU (CPU is easy to get via SMC)
I need the Gpu graphic processor.

Comment: Sorry, I am going to make an appointment to the ophthalmologist...

Comment: @Emmanuel it is ok :) thanks anyway!

Comment: how do you get GPU percentage usage with objective-c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq

> Q: How can I get information on GPU temperature from my application?
>   On Microsoft Windows platforms, NVIDIA's NVAPI gives access to GPU
>   temperature and many other low-level GPU functions
>
> Under Linux, the "nvidia-smi" utility, which is included with the
>   standard driver install, also displays GPU temperature for all
>   installed devices.

**EDIT**

While looking further about "nvidia-smi" utility which has been provided by linux based system, i found that they have provided C based API to fetch the GPU temperature.

https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml
https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface

https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML_cuda5/nvml.4.304.55.pdf

From manual, I could see that below API can be used to find out which has been provided by "nvidia-smi":

```
7.9.2.8 nvmlReturn_t DECLDIR nvmlUnitGetTemperature (nvmlUnit_t unit, unsigned int type, unsigned
int  temp)
Retrieves the temperature readings for the unit, in degrees C.
For S-class products.
Depending on the product, readings may be available for intake (type=0), exhaust (type=1) and board (type=2).
Parameters:
unit The identifier of the target unit
type The type of reading to take
temp Reference in which to return the intake temperature
Returns:
• NVML_SUCCESS if temp has been populated
• NVML_ERROR_UNINITIALIZED if the library has not been successfully initialized
• NVML_ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT if unit or type is invalid or temp is NULL
• NVML_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED if this is not an S-class product
• NVML_ERROR_UNKNOWN on any unexpected error
```

Hope this would be useful and this way you can achieve your requirement. "nvidia-smi" internally uses the above API to find out the temperature of GPU which which user get.This is command line utility provided by NVIDIA.

Comment: But doesn't SMC on (MBP for example) should know the INFO to adjust FAN speed relatively ? I am sure there is some generic way and can be accessed from with in userscope.

Comment: @Roma-MT: Well May be I am not very much aware about GPU and my information was to let you know based on my finding on your question. However it looks like you are trying to get/find tool low level information about hardware in user space mode. Normally these information are and should be reserved for kernel mode.Anyway I do not have anything further to update on my post.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much!! Kernel mode is acceptable as well ))

Comment: @Roma-MT: Check out my edited post. Hope this would be useful for you.

Comment: I will  try to implement it, I will update you as soon as I will know the answer , thank you MR :)

Comment: The sad part that it is only for NVIDIA so based on this solution I will have to implement ATI and NVIDIA separately , there is more GC manufactures ? :)

Comment: @Roma-MT: I do not think it would be possible to write such a low level code in generic way which would work for all type of GPUs. You would have to be dependent on the hardware vender to fetch such information. You continue with your proceeding :)

Comment: Well that's going to take some time :) also this API can be accessed from user mode isn't it? just need to define all this mysterious structures :)

Comment: It was great answer,however I guess I found more generic way to dial with that. here is [SMC keys documentation](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/fakesmc/wiki/Known_SMC_Keys/history) ,
still a huge thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

try this one named "magican", it's icon is an elephant, cpu and gpu temperature can show in the status bar,when click,you can see the progresses you launched
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekeW2.png

download from http://www.magicansoft.com/

Comment: Yes I saw this software, but I am looking for library or native API to achieve this data directly from kernel using obj-c or c.
(thanks for fast reply) edited my question to stop further misunderstanding.

Comment: i see, look at this  http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/194755/find-cpu-temperature-with-c-code-in-linux

Comment: well it is [C]PU temperature :)